# SSL with heroku-php-nginx on localhost

Tags: ssl, heroku, nginx

I'm running an app with heroku using their php buildpack.

Therefore my app starts with `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx.conf public/` where `nginx.conf` is my custom nginx config file that gets appended inside a `server` directive here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/master/conf/nginx/heroku.conf.php#L60.

I'm wondering how I can set this up in a way where I can get ssl to work locally while still having a config that is consistent in both prod and dev?

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: I ended up using https://github.com/cameronhunter/local-ssl-proxy.